# iPhone 6s display color profile differences between devices

Tags: iphone, color

Comparing three iPhone 6s side by side, I noticed fairly significant differences in the appearance of colors between them. One in particular is much warmer looking, especially for whites. I have confirmed that nightshift is off and that no screen accessibility settings are enabled.

I tried to capture the difference in the image below with limited success.

[image]

In person, the one on the left is noticeable warmer looking, and the one on the right is redder than the one in the middle (or the middle one is greener than the one on the right).

Could any other setting be effecting the display colors? Or is this color variation just expected for three different devices with different histories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know the history of each of these iPhones?

This may not necessarily explain the difference in your case, but one factor that can result in this difference is the use of non-genuine parts. For example, I've seen this type of differentiation in iPhones that have had screens replaced with 3rd party screens.

Otherwise you could check that the following settings found in **Settings > General > Accessibility** are the same in all iPhones:

- Display Accommodations > Colour Filters
- Display Accommodations > Auto-Brightness
- Display Accommodations > Reduce White Point
- Increase Contrast > Reduce Transparency
- Increase Contrast > Darken Colours

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I confirmed those settings are the same across the devices but still see the color variation. Two of these are rental units that very well could have had screen replacements or been mistreated at some point, so that may very well explain these differences